# Code Highlighting for Subversion/Apache Server

Tags: linux, svn, apache, websvn

I have beeen looking around for a way to add code highlighting to my Subversion and Apache installation that hosts my local subversion projects. It runs on Fedora Core 10 installed in a VM. I would like to use [syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) but I have not idea how i can get Apache to automatically insert the required javascript into my source code files (without tainting the source).

It is possible to modify my existing installation of Apache 2.2/SVN 1.5.5 to use syntaxhighlighter? ([this is what it looks like](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/))

There is a project called WebSVN hosted by Collabnet that seems to have something similar built in, however after the trouble I've gone to get the web subversion working (And Fedora configured nicely), I don't want to use OpenCollabnet's version of WebSVN. Plus their version does not support the latest subversion and Apache.

How can I add some form of code highlighting to my Apache that serves the subversion source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trac is installed, I checked out Enscript, SilverCity and Pygments.
There were no packages for FC10 for the first two, but there was a Pygments package.....it looks rather nice.
[Demos here](http://pygments.org/demo/)

The C++ highlighting is what i'm interested in, it looks decent: [C++ Highlighting](http://pygments.org/demo/1388/)

Although Pygments is obviously not as nice as syntaxhighlighter, which I would still prefer to use if someone knows an easy way to setup.

Answer (score 2):

I was using [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for web-based project management software. It does issue tracking and wiki, but it also provides a repository browser which has [syntax coloring](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSyntaxColoring). It supports a bunch of different syntax colorers. GNU Enscript, SilverCity, Pygments

Comment: I'm looking into this right now. Installing Trac, ill get back to you